# How to improve query performance of regex array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

My program is designed to take input from a file containing a list of fingerprint,
This file has more than 20,000 fingerprint records, the file looks like so:

```
abc     Body="123"
think       Header="think"
xxx         Response=="xxx"
fff         Body!="abc"

etc.
```

What I need to do is load this file to a vector(read the file and generate regular expression dynamically),and search the vector by string:

```cpp
// abc  Body="123"
struct Rule
{
    std::string name; // abc
    std::string type; // Body
    std::string op;   // =, ==, !=, do regex matching according to op
    std::string rule; // "123"
    std::shared_ptr<re2::RE2> reg;
}


std::vector<Rule> rules = load('fingerprint.txt');
```

The approximate content of the load function is as follows:

```cpp
std::vector<Rule> load (const std::string& file)
{
    std::vector<Rule> res;
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(file,line))
    {
        Rule rule;
        // line = abc   Body="123"
        // rule.name = "abc";
        // rule.type = "Body";
        // rule.op   = "=";
        // rule.rule = "\"123\"";
        rule = parse_line(line);
        rule.reg.reset(new re2::RE2(rule.rule));
        res.push_back(rule);
    }
    return res;
}
```

The following is my query function:

```cpp
struct QueryObject
{
    std::string header;
    std::string body;
    std::string title;
    std::string response;
}

// std::vector<Rule> rules = load('fingerprint.txt');

std::string get_query_str(const Rule& rule, const QueryObject& obj)
{
    if(rule.type=="Header") return obj.header;
    if(rule.type=="Body") return obj.body;
    etc...
    
}


std::vector<std::string> query(const QueryObject& obj)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::string query_str;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < rules.size(); ++i)
    {
        const Rule &rule = rules[i];
        query_str = get_query_str(rule,obj);
        if (rule.op == "=" 
            && RE2::PartialMatch(query_str, *rule.reg))
        {
            result.push_back(rule.name);
        }
        else if(rule.op == "!=" 
                && !RE2::PartialMatch(query_str, *rule.reg))
        {
            result.push_back(rule.name);
        }
        else if(rule.op == "==" && query_str == rule.rule)
        {
            result.push_back(rule.name);
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

**I have tried using multi-threads, but the improvement is not significant. The pseudocode is as follows:**

```cpp
// reload query function
std::vector<std::string> query(const QueryObject& obj, size_t begin, size_t end)
{
    for(size_t i = begin; i < end; ++i)
    {
        //...
    }
}
// std::vector<Rule> rules = load('fingerprint.txt');
QueryObject obj;
auto task1 = thread_pool.enque(query, obj,0,rules.size()/2);
auto tast2 = thread_pool.enque(query, obj,rules.size()/2+1, rules.size());

// use task1.get(), task2.get() to get the results of query()
```

**I have tested this function,it takes a long time to query one record. How can I improve the queey efficiency?**

| Single thread | 2 threads |
| --- | --- |
| 6980ms | 6647ms |

**Any help is greatly appreciated.** English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part.

---

**Update:**

Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Build Tool: xmake
compiler command：

```bash
xmake f -p linux -a x86_64 -m release
xmake build -w my_app
```

The cxxflags generated by xmake for the makefile may have the following content:

```
fingerprint_CXXFLAGS=-m64 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O2 -isystem /home/hsiao/.xmake/packages/f/fmt/10.1.1/include  -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG
```

xmake.lua:

```lua
add_rules("mode.debug", "mode.release")
add_requires("fmt","re2","spdlog","libcurl","openssl","gtest","nlohmann_json")
add_rules("plugin.compile_commands.autoupdate", {outputdir = ".vscode"})


if is_mode("debug") then 
    add_defines("DEBUG")
    set_symbols("debug")
    set_optimize("none")
end 


if is_mode("release") then 
    set_strip("all")
    add_cxflags("-fomit-frame-pointer")
    add_mxflags("-fomit-frame-pointer")
    set_optimize("faster")
end 

target("analyze_fingerprint")
    set_kind("binary")
    add_files("src/*.cpp")
    add_packages("fmt","re2","spdlog","nlohmann_json")
    set_targetdir("bin")
```

The code for measuring the execution time:

```cpp
QueryObject obj;
obj.title="ruijie";

auto begin = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto result = query(obj);
auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> duration = end - begin;
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? How do you compile? How do you benchmark?

Comment: Using a `shared_ptr` is probably not necessary and regex is most likely overkill too. Instead of a homemade thread pool, you could try using a standard algorithm with a parallel execution policy. Note: `rules.size()/2+1` will miss the middle element.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I use g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 and I use xmake to build my project.
I haven't done any benchmarking yet, but I have tested the time to query one record (it takes over 6,000 milliseconds per query).

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you for the reminder.  RE2 can't be moved or copied, so I use shared_ptr. What should I use if I don't want to use shared_ptr?

Comment: We need the exact compilation commands (not "I use xmake") and the exact command you derive your 6000ms figure from.

Comment: @programmerHsiao In that case I'd use a `std::unique_ptr` which is more lightweight than a `std::shared_ptr` - but I really wonder if you need all the flexibility and slowness that regex brings.

Comment: Don't copy it, move it.

Comment: Underling data in vector might got move when insert new one. [https://godbolt.org/z/1sq93v818](https://godbolt.org/z/1sq93v818). use reserve or change container should help.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The content related to test method and compilation command has been updated.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like both compilation and time measurement are OK. Now the next step would be profiling your code. I normally use valgrind with callgrind tool and kcachegrind visualizer, but gprof could work too.

Comment: I will try profiling my code using valgrind,  this is my first year programming. Thanks!

Comment: There's one thing you can improve right now. String comparison is expensive, so make an enum for operations and another for rule types, translate strings like "Body" and "==" to enums when you parse, and switch on those.

Comment: If the rule does not contain any special regex characters like '.' or '*', then a simple string::find might be faster (or not, you need to test that). Also, combining all regexes of the same type and op into one giant regex and matching it once, instead of matching each one separately in a loop, might be faster. That is, if you have `Body="123"` and  `Body="456"`, it might be beneficial to match `"123|456"` instead of doing two separate matches. Again, you need to test for that.

Comment: The `==` matches can be taken out of the rules list and converted to a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` lookup. The other thing is indeed to combine multiple regexps into one. You can use the `(?<rule_name>re)` syntax to pluck out which rule matched.

Comment: I would change `Rule::type` to `std::string QueryObject::*` and avoid to copy that string.

Comment: Is returning `std::vector<std::string_view>` possible to avoid string allocation?

Comment: Your bottleneck should be reading from the file.  Searches and sorts usually only become benchmark when dealing with over 1E9 records.  I recommend using multiple buffers for reading.  Minimum two threads.  One thread reads file into one or more buffers.  The quantity of buffers is used to adjust the wait period of the main thread.  When reading thread has read enough buffers, it signals the main thread to start processing the data.

Comment: Read up on *database theory*.  IMHO, you need to dump all the records in a vector.  You'll want to build up index tables (a.k.a. std::map) for faster retrieval from the vector.  The index table will be of `<key, vector-index>`.  Use the index table to get vector index of a given key.  Create one index table for each search key or combination.

Comment: If it smells like a database or behaves like a database, you should use a database.  Database code has been optimized for data accesses. :-)  There are small ones you can put into your program and larger databases that require separate servers.